# C pluginsystem: symbol lookup error

Tags: c, plugins, shared-libraries, posix

I am writing a plugin system which is separated other 3 modules:

1. *plugin_system.c* - the core of the system
2. *list.c* - contains a linked list implementation for plugins' storage
3. *plugin_interface.h* - contains the declaration needed by plugins, has no source file associated with

*plugin_interface.h* only contains only of types and the function:

```
 extern int plugin_register(PluginManager *plug_manager, const char *name, Plugin *plug);
```

which is defined in *plugin_system.c*

When loading a plugin, the plugin system look for a funcion `init_plugname()` and call it, that function must call `plugin_register` to register the plugin.

The program is compiled with complex recursive Makefiles (not the best idea), but what I try to achieve is:

I compile the plugin system object in the main program folder, it is then linked with the main program. From `make` execution:

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -std=gnu99  -D DEBUG -g -fPIC -c -o /home/kowa/code/reseaux/projet/ringo/c/bin/list.o list.c
gcc -Wall -O2 -std=gnu99  -D DEBUG -g -fPIC -c -o /home/kowa/code/reseaux/projet/ringo/c/bin/plugin_system.o plugin_system.c
```

A plugin is compiled with `gcc -fPIC -c -o plugname.o plugname.c plug_system.o` followed by `gcc -o plugname.so plugname.o plug_system.o -shared`

I try to load the plugin in my main program and get this error:

```
symbol lookup error: ./plugins/zyva.so: undefined symbol: exists
```

`exists` is a function in the list module used by the *plugin_system* module to store plugins, the `plugin_register` function mentionned aboved calls it.

I've never done that kind of system before and I'm not an expert in shared library, I guess the problem is from how I compile the whole project, I may miss some linkage...

Comment: Don't use have another compliation command to generate "plug_system.o"? Please show us all your compilation commands.

Comment: I added the compilation commands for the plugin system, I can put all the commands if you wan't but the others are for other part of the projects so it may not be relevant...

Comment: I tried to create a small dynamic library with two object files the way you are doing it, and I got no problem to link them together... Are you sure there is no error in how you write `exists()` in each source file? Make sure you did not write `exist()`.

Comment: Oh damn! `exists()` [already exists](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exists). Try renaming it just to be sure.

Comment: No it's not that sorry, I think I see the problem in your linking command.

Comment: I renamed it to `mem` and have the same issue, by the way I have no manual entry for `exists` on my system.

Comment: What happens if you try to use your shared library the classical way?

Comment: Do you properly use `dlopen()` `dlsym()` and `dclose()`? It seems to me you are not using `dlsym()`...

Comment: Giving all those explanations are a good thing, but this is not enough. I am not sure to understand exactly what you are doing, and so I am not able to get the same error message as you. Please create a new empty project in an empty folder and build a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that way I won't have to assume what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to link the plugin with *list.o* which is used by the *plugin_system.o*...