# C plugin system: dlopen fails

Tags: c, linux, networking, plugins

as a continuation to this post [C pluginsystem: symbol lookup error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797376/c-pluginsystem-symbol-lookup-error?noredirect=1#comment61173064_36797376), I am still writing my plugin system and encounter new bugs.

To recap what the plugins are, the program consists of a network application interfaced by a shell, messages has a type and therefore can be use to create applications on the network. For exemple, a possible application would be a chat or a transfert application.

So shell commands can send message of a particular application on the network, when a message is received, if it corresponds to a particular application then an action function is executed with the message content as argument, it could be the application.

A plugin is a shared library with an init function that register it's commands and actions. A command could just be a simple command that doesn't interact with the network, and that's why I achieved at the moment.

The plugin system consists in modules:

1. *plugin_system.c*
2. *list.c* used by the first module to store plugins

The network part consists in:

1. *protocol.c* main part of the protocol
2. *message.c* main part for message treatment
3. *application.c* main part used to program applications
4. *common.c* file with ccommon functions
5. *network.c* useful network functions

The modules in protocole are all interdependent, I have split files for conveniency.
All modules are compiled with -fPIC option.

To compile a plugin called *plug.c* wich doesn't interact with the network, I use:

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -std=gnu99  -D DEBUG -g -fPIC -c -o plug.o plug.c
gcc -Wall -O2 -std=gnu99  -D DEBUG -g -o plug.so plug.o plugin_system.o list.o -shared
```

And it works perfectly, the library is loaded with `dlopen` with no problem, the init function loaded with `dlsym` and executed correctly so the plugin is registered, I then executed the command and I can see that it work.

Now I wan't to add supports for network communications for the plugins, so I have modified the same test plugin that I used which has just a command to print a message. I have had a call to `sendappmessage_all` a function that send a message to everyone over the network, defined in *message.c*.

I can compile the new plugin without adding the network module objects, it compile, the plugin loads correctly, but when it call `sendappmessage_all` obviously it fails with the message

```
 symbol lookup error: ./plugins/zyva.so: undefined symbol: sendappmessage_all
```

So to make it work, I should like the plugin with network modules so that's what I have done with

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -std=gnu99  -D DEBUG -g -o plug.so plug.o plugin_system.o list.o protocol.o message.o thread.o common.o application.o network.o -shared
```

It compile but when I try to load the plugin, `dlopen` return `NULL`.
I have also tried to add just one module, at worst it would only result in an `undefined symbol` error, but I `dlopen` still return `NULL`.

I know it's a lot of informations and on the otherside you probably wan't to see the code but I tried to be the clearer in the most succint way I could be because is way more complex and bigger than the post.

Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Check the symbol table with objdump and see if the symbol is exported. Try __attribute__((used)) in sendappmessage_all and tell me what happens.

Comment: Yes I can see it, what do you mean by "Try __attribute__((used))"?

Comment: It's an attribute used to keep gcc from removing an unused function; if the symbol is in the dynamic symbol table dlsym should be able to find it, so you don't need it. Can you post a minimal example that reproduce your behavior?

Comment: I thought about it before trying to write some code, and something that doesn't appear in my post and may be the source of the problem is that the modules in the network part use global variables to store network informations (for example the receivers' adresses), then when the main program try to load the plugin he found the same globals in the plugin, and that's not possible. This is just thoughts, purely hypotetical because I'm new into the domain of dynamic linking, but could it be the reason why `dlopen` fails?

Comment: In fact no, I've just written a some example that mimics this behaviour and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you compile the plugin system (i.e. functions called by plugins), and link it to the final executable, the linker does not export the symbols used by the plugins in the dynamic symbol table.

There are two options:

1. Use `-rdynamic` when linking the final executable, adding all symbols to the dynamic symbol table.
2. Use `-Wl,-dynamic-list,plugin-system.list` when linking the final executable, adding symbols listed in file `plugin-system.list` to the dynamic symbol table.

   The file format is simple:

   ```
    {
        sendappmessage_all;
        plugin_*;
    };
   ```

   In other words, you can list either each symbol name (function or data structure), or a glob pattern that matches the desired symbol names. Remember the semicolon after each symbol, and after the closing brace, or you'll get a "syntax error in dynamic list" error at link time.

Note that just marking a function "used" via [`__attribute__((used))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bused_007d-function-attribute-3258) is not sufficient to make the linker include it in the dynamic symbol table (with GCC 4.8.4 and GNU ld 2.24, at least).

---

Since the OP thinks what I wrote above is incorrect, here is a fully verifiable proof of the above.

First, a simple **main.c** that loads plugin files named on the command line, and executes their `const char *register_plugin(void);` function. Because the function name is shared across all plugins, we need to link them locally (`RTLD_LOCAL`).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static const char *load_plugin(const char *pathname)
{
    const char    *errmsg;
    void          *handle; /* We deliberately leak the handle */
    const char * (*initfunc)(void);

    if (!pathname || !*pathname)
        return "No path specified";

    dlerror();
    handle = dlopen(pathname, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL);
    errmsg = dlerror();
    if (errmsg)
        return errmsg;

    initfunc = dlsym(handle, "register_plugin");
    errmsg = dlerror();
    if (errmsg)
        return errmsg;

    return initfunc();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *errmsg;
    int         arg;

    if (argc < 1 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s plugin [ plugin ... ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
        errmsg = load_plugin(argv[arg]);
        if (errmsg) {
            fflush(stdout);
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[arg], errmsg);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    fflush(stdout);
    fprintf(stderr, "All plugins loaded successfully.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The plugins will have access via certain functions (and/or variables), declared in **plugin_system.h**:

```
#ifndef   PLUGIN_SYSTEM_H
#define   PLUGIN_SYSTEM_H

extern void plugin_message(const char *);

#endif /* PLUGIN_SYSTEM_H */
```

They are implemented in **plugin_system.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void plugin_message(const char *msg)
{
    fputs(msg, stderr);
}
```

and listed as dynamic symbols in **plugin_system.list**:

```
{
    plugin_message;
};
```

We'll also need a plugin, **plugin_foo.c**:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "plugin_system.h"

const char *register_plugin(void) __attribute__((used));
const char *register_plugin(void)
{
    plugin_message("Plugin 'foo' is here.\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

and just to remove any confusion about what effect there is having each plugin a registration function by the same name, another plugin named **plugin_bar.c**:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "plugin_system.h"

const char *register_plugin(void) __attribute__((used));
const char *register_plugin(void)
{
    plugin_message("Plugin 'bar' is here.\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

To make all of this easy to compile, we'll need a **Makefile**:

```
CC              := gcc
CFLAGS          := -Wall -Wextra -O2
LDFLAGS         := -ldl -Wl,-dynamic-list,plugin_system.list
PLUGIN_CFLAGS   := $(CFLAGS)
PLUGIN_LDFLAGS  := -fPIC
PLUGINS         := plugin_foo.so plugin_bar.so
PROGS           := example

.phony: all clean progs plugins

all: clean progs plugins

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(PLUGINS) $(PROGS)

%.so: %.c
    $(CC) $(PLUGIN_CFLAGS) $^ $(PLUGIN_LDFLAGS) -shared -Wl,-soname,$@ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^

plugins: $(PLUGINS)

progs: $(PROGS)

example: main.o plugin_system.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

Note that Makefiles require intendation by tabs, not spaces; listing the file here always converts them to spaces. So, if you paste the above to a file, you'll need to fix the indentation, via e.g.

```
sed -e 's|^  *|\t|' -i Makefile
```

It is safe to run that more than once; the worst it can do, is mess up your "human-readable" layout.

Compile the above using e.g.

```
make
```

and run it via e.g.

```
./example ./plugin_bar.so ./plugin_foo.so
```

which shall output

```
Plugin 'bar' is here.
Plugin 'foo' is here.
All plugins loaded successfully.
```

to standard error.

Personally, I prefer to register my plugins via a structure, with a version number, and at least one function pointer (to the initialization function). This lets me load all plugins before initializing them, and resolve e.g. interplugin conflicts or dependencies. (In other words, I use a structure with a fixed name, rather than a function with a fixed name, to identify plugins.)

Now, as to `__attribute__((used))`. If you modify `plugin_system.c` into

```
#include <stdio.h>

void plugin_message(const char *msg) __attribute__((used));

void plugin_message(const char *msg)
{
    fputs(msg, stderr);
}
```

and modify the Makefile to have `LDFLAGS := -ldl` only, the example program and plugins will compile just fine, but running it will yield

```
./plugin_bar.so: ./plugin_bar.so: undefined symbol: plugin_message.
```

In other words, if the API exported to plugins is compiled in a separate compilation unit, you will need to use either `-rdynamic` or `-Wl,-dynamic-list,plugin-system.list` to ensure the functions are included in the dynamic symbol table in the final executable; the `used` attribute does not suffice.

---

If you want all and only non-`static` functions and symbols in `plugin_system.o` included in dynamic symbol table in the final binary, you can e.g. modify the end of the `Makefile` into

```
example: main.o plugin_system.o
    @rm -f plugin_system.list
    ./list_globals.sh plugin_system.o > plugin_system.list
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

with **list_globals.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ $# -ge 1 ] || exit 0
export LANG=C LC_ALL=C
IFS=:
IFS="$(printf '\t ')"

printf '{\n'
readelf -s "$@" | while read Num Value Size Type Bind Vis Ndx Name Dummy ; do
    [ -n "$Name" ] || continue
    if [ "$Bind:$Type" = "GLOBAL:FUNC" ]; then
        printf '    %s;\n' "$Name"
    elif [ "$Bind:$Type:$Ndx" = "GLOBAL:OBJECT:COM" ]; then
        printf '    %s;\n' "$Name"
    fi
done
printf '};\n'
```

Remember to make the script executable, `chmod u+x list_globals.sh`.

Comment: Actually it does, see the comment about objdump under the post... But thank you for the information, it's relevant.

Comment: I apologize for not trying your proposition before answering you because you're right! It works with the `-rdynamic` option.
About the `-Wl,-dynamic-list,plugin-system.list`, what should I put exactly in it?
`sendappmessage_all` calls several other functions, so do I need to put them all?
 And can I really put a `*` or should I replace it with all functions' names?

Comment: `-rdynamic` adds all symbols to dynamic symbol table. In `plugin_system.list`, you should include **all symbols the plugins may access** that are not part of libraries used by the project. In other words, the symbols that your plugin system defines for plugins to be used. I'll add a small snippet on how to make that easier.

Comment: To clarify the previous comment, `-rdynamic` is a simple option; the `-Wl,-dynamic-list,` is a more finegrained version. I added `list_globals.sh` to my answer as an example how you can pick all globals (non-`static`s) from one or more object files, and list them in `plugin_system.list`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is pretty neat! I still have one question, if `sendappmessage_all` calls another function, for example `sendpacket`, do I need to put it in the list? If so, I guess this is a recursive process so it also applies to `sendpacket`.

Comment: Also if `sendpacket` use a global variable should I put it in the list? `sendpacket` is not part of the pulgin system, but it is used by the plugin system in `sendappmessage_all`. Do I need to declare it with ` __attribute__((used))` in its file?

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto: No, only functions and objects that are accessed directly by the plugin code need to be listed. (When the plugin code calls a function or accesses a symbol, it must *find* it; that's what the dynamic symbol table is for. When the plugin code calls such a function, it jumps into the main executable code, which doesn't need the symbols to be dynamic, as it is already linked to them.) As far as I can tell, the `used` attribute is irrelevant here.

Comment: Again thank you for your reply, I have made a huge step in the comprehension of dynamic linking thanks to you.