# -rdynamic for select symbols only?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, dynamic-linking, dlopen

Scenario:

Executable loads shared object at run time via dlopen.

The shared object references some symbol (a function) that is actually compiled into the main executable.

This works fine if I add -rdynamic to gcc when linking the executable.

-rdynamic exports all non-static symbols of the executable. My shared object only needs a select few.

Question: Is there a way to achieve the effect of -rdynamic, but restricted the the few select symbols that I know are needed by my shared object?

Edit:

At least two people misunderstood the question, so I try to clarify:

This question is about exporting a symbol from the main executable.

This question is **not** about exporting a symbol from a dynamic library.

Here is a minimal example:

func.h, the common header file

```
#include <stdio.h>
void func(void);
```

main.c, the main executable code:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "func.h"

// this function is later called by plugin
void func(void) {
  printf("func\n");
}

int main() {
  void * plugin_lib = dlopen("./plugin.so", RTLD_NOW);
  printf("dlopen -> %p, error: %s\n", plugin_lib, dlerror());

  // find and call function "plugin" in plugin.so
  void (*p)(void); // declares p as pointer to function
  p = dlsym(plugin_lib, "plugin");
  p();

  return 0;
}
```

plugin.c, code for the plugin that is loaded at runtime:

```
#include "func.h"

void plugin()
{
  printf("plugin\n");
  func();
}
```

If I compile with

```
$ gcc -o main main.c -ldl
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -o plugin.so plugin.c
```

Then plugin.so cannot be loaded, because it references the symbol func, which cannot be resolved:

```
$ ./main
dlopen -> (nil), error: ./plugin.so: undefined symbol: func
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I can convince the main executable to export all its global symbols by compiling with -rdynamic:

```
$ gcc -rdynamic -o main main.c -ldl
$ ./main
dlopen -> 0x75e030, error: (null)
plugin
func
```

But this fills the dynamic symbol table unnecessarily with all symbols.

(This dynamic symbol table can be inspected with `nm -D main`.)

The question is, how can I add only "func" to the dynamic symbol table of the main executable, and not everything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explicitly exporting shared library functions in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164827/explicitly-exporting-shared-library-functions-in-linux)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to call function in executable from my library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292473/how-to-call-function-in-executable-from-my-library)

Comment: @ninjalj Nice find! That question itself is not my question. But it has an answer http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6298434/revisions that also anwers my question.

Comment: @LudwigSchulze: I have shown an explicit example of how to do this [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36807145/1475978). The original question there is pretty much exactly the same situation as you have here.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with the visibility attribute of GCC.

Declare the function you need to export with `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))` flag. Then compile your whole library passing `-fvisibility=hidden` argument to GCC.

For full explanation on this, refer to the following [GCC documentation page](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility).

Comment: Thank you, but No. My question is about exporting symbols from the main executable, not from a library.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's harder to achieve this for executables. You need to generate a list of symbols that you want to export and then add `-Wl,--dynamic-list=symfile.txt` to `LDFLAGS`.

[Here's example](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/4920d3228938c5ca6d6dd267da640e9ff65b6802/lib/Driver/Tools.cpp#L3184) of how it's done in Clang (and [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/lib/sanitizer_common/scripts/gen_dynamic_list.py)'s the script they use to generate the symbols file).

Comment: Yes, -Wl,--dynamic-list=<text file with list of symbols> is the way to do it. See https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6298434/revisions for an answer that gives an example symbol file.

Answer (score 0):

greydet's answer is perfectly applicable for executables; after all, it's all just ELFs

The `-Wl,--dynamic-list=` solution is available even in ancient versions of GCC, so it is more compatible. Nowadays, there is no reason not to use `-fvisibility=` to achieve the same.

(source: https://flameeyes.blog/2011/01/20/hide-those-symbols and https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Exported-Symbols-of-Shared-Libraries.html)

```c
// main.c

int fsym(void) { return 42; }

__attribute__((visibility("default"))) int gsym(void) { return 24; }

int main(void) { return 0; }
```

Compile this with `gcc -fvisibility=hidden -rdynamic main.c` and examine the symbols with `nm --dynamic a.out`

```
% gcc -fvisibility=hidden -rdynamic main.c
% nm --dynamic a.out | grep sym                    
0000000000401111 T gsym
```

Notice that `fsym` is not exported, while `gsym` is.