# avoid LD_PRELOAD: Wrap library and provide functionality requested from libc

Tags: c, shared-libraries, ld-preload

I have a shared library, say `somelib.so`, which uses `ioctl` from libc (according to `objdump`).

My goal is to write a new library that wraps around `somelib.so` and provides a custom `ioctl`. I want to avoid preloading a library to ensure that only the calls in `somelib.so` use the custom `ioctl`.

Here is my current snippet:

```
typedef int (*entryfunctionFromSomelib_t) (int par, int opt);
typedef int (*ioctl_t) (int fd, int request, void *data);
ioctl_t real_ioctl = NULL;

int ioctl(int fd, int request, void *data )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "trying to wrap ioctl\n" );
    void *handle = dlopen( "libc.so.6", RTLD_NOW );
    if (!handle)
        fprintf( stderr, "Error loading libc.so.6: %s\n", strerror(errno) );

    real_ioctl = (ioctl_t) dlsym( handle, "ioctl" );
    return real_ioctl( fd, request, data);
}

int entryfunctionFromSomelib( int par, int opt ) {
    void *handle = dlopen( "/.../somelib.so", RTLD_NOW );
    if (!handle)
        fprintf( stderr, "Error loading somelib.so: %s\n", strerror(errno) );

    real_entryfunctionFromSomelib = entryfunctionFromSomelib_t dlsym( handle, "entryfunctionFromSomelib" );
    return real_entryfunctionFromSomelib( par, opt );
}
```

However, it does not in work in the sense that the calls to `ioctl` form `somelib.so` are not redirected to my custom `ioctl` implementation. How can I enforce that the wrapped `somelib.so` does so?

======================

Additional information added after @Nominal Animal post:

Here some information from mylib.so (somelib.so after edit) obtained via `readelf -s | grep functionname`:

```
   246: 0000000000000000   121 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND dlsym@GLIBC_2.2.5 (11)
 42427: 0000000000000000   121 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND dlsym@@GLIBC_2.2.5


   184: 0000000000000000    37 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND ioctl@GLIBC_2.2.5 (6)
 42364: 0000000000000000    37 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND ioctl@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

After 'patching' mylib.so it also shows the new function as:

```
   184: 0000000000000000    37 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND iqct1@GLIBC_2.2.5 (6)
```

I 'versioned' and exported the symbols from my wrap_mylib library for which `readelf` now shows:

```
25: 0000000000000d15   344 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 iqct1@GLIBC_2.2.5
63: 0000000000000d15   344 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 iqct1@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

However, when I try to `dlopen` wrap_mylib I get the following error:

```
symbol iqct1, version GLIBC_2.2.5 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

Is that maybe because mylib.so tries to `dlsym` `iqct1` from libc.so.6 ?

Comment: Can you recompile the original `mylib.so`?

Comment: @DanielJour no. I just realize that maybe the naming "mylib" is stupid as I don't have the sources and can't recompile it. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If binutils' `objcopy` could modify dynamic symbols, and the `mylib.so` is an ELF dynamic library, we could use

```
mv  mylib.so  old.mylib.so
objcopy --redefine-sym ioctl=mylib_ioctl  old.mylib.so  mylib.so
```

to rename the symbol name in the library from `ioctl` to `mylib_ioctl`, so we could implement

```
int mylib_ioctl(int fd, int request, void *data);
```

in another library or object linked to the final binaries.

Unfortunately, [this feature is not implemented](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2009-12/msg00239.html) (as of early 2017 at least).

---

We can solve this using an ugly hack, if the replacement symbol name is exactly the same length as the original name. The symbol name is a string (both preceded and followed by a nul byte) in the ELF file, so we can just replace it using e.g. GNU sed:

```
LANG=C LC_ALL=C sed -e 's|\x00ioctl\x00|\x00iqct1\x00|g' old.mylib.so > mylib.so
```

This replaces the name from `ioctl()` to `iqct1()`. It is obviously less than optimal, but it seems the simplest option here.

If you find you need to add version information to the `iqct1()` function you implement, with GCC you can simply add a line similar to

```
__asm__(".symver iqct1,iqct1@GLIBC_2.2.5");
```

where the version follows the `@` character.

---

Here is a practical example, showing how I tested this in practice.

First, let's create **mylib.c**, representing the sources for mylib.c (that the OP does not have -- otherwise just altering the sources and recompiling the library would solve the issue):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int myfunc(const char *message)
{
    int retval = 0;

    if (message) {
        const char *end = message;
        int         saved_errno;
        ssize_t     n;

        while (*end)
            end++;

        saved_errno = errno;

        while (message < end) {
            n = write(STDERR_FILENO, message, (size_t)(end - message));
            if (n > 0)
                message += n;
            else {
                if (n == -1)
                    retval = errno;
                else
                    retval = EIO;
                break;
            }
        }

        errno = saved_errno;
    }

    return retval;
}
```

The only function exported is `myfunc(message)`, as declared in **mylib.h**:

```
#ifndef   MYLIB_H
#define   MYLIB_H

int myfunc(const char *message);

#endif /* MYLIB_H */
```

Let's compile the mylib.c into a dynamic shared library, `mylib.so`:

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -fPIC -shared mylib.c -Wl,-soname,libmylib.so -o mylib.so
```

Instead of `write()` from the C library (it's a POSIX function just like `ioctl()`, not a standard C one), we wish to use `mywrt()` of our own design in our own program. The above command saves the original library as `mylib.so` (while naming it internally as `libmylib.so`), so we can use

```
sed -e 's|\x00write\x00|\x00mywrt\x00|g' mylib.so > libmylib.so
```

to alter the symbol name, saving the modified library as `libmylib.so`.

Next, we need a test executable, that provides the `ssize_t mywrt(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);` function (the prototype being the same as the [`write(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) function it replaces. **test.c**:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mylib.h"

ssize_t mywrt(int fd, const void *buffer, size_t bytes)
{
    printf("write(%d, %p, %zu);\n", fd, buffer, bytes);
    return bytes;
}
__asm__(".symver mywrt,mywrt@GLIBC_2.2.5");

int main(void)
{
    myfunc("Hello, world!\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `.symver` line specifies version `GLIBC_2.2.5` for `mywrt`.

The version depends on the C library used. In this case, I ran `objdump -T $(locate libc.so) 2>/dev/null | grep -e ' write$'`, which gave me

```
00000000000f66d0  w   DF .text  000000000000005a  GLIBC_2.2.5 write
```

the second to last field of which is the version needed.

Because the `mywrt` symbol needs to be exported for the dynamic library to use, I created **test.syms**:

```
{
    mywrt;
};
```

To compile the test executable, I used

```
gcc -Wall -O2 test.c -Wl,-dynamic-list,test.syms -L. -lmylib  -o test
```

Because `libmylib.so` is in the current working directory, we need to add current directory to the dynamic library search path:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then, we can run our test binary:

```
./test
```

It will output something like

```
write(2, 0xADDRESS, 14);
```

because that's what the `mywrt()` function does. If we want to check the unmodified output, we can run `mv -f mylib.so libmylib.so` and rerun `./test`, which will then output just

```
Hello, world!
```

This shows that this approach, although depending on very crude binary modification of the shared library file (using `sed` -- but only because `objcopy` does not (yet) support `--redefine-sym` on dynamic symbols), should work just fine in practice.

This is also a perfect example of how *open source* is superior to proprietary libraries: the amount of effort already spent in trying to fix this minor issue is at least an order of magnitude higher than it would have been to rename the `ioctl` call in the library sources to e.g. `mylib_ioctl()`, and recompile it.

---

Interposing `dlsym()` (from `<dlfcn.h>`, as standardized in POSIX.1-2001) in the final binary seems necessary in OP's case.

Let's assume the original dynamic library is modified using

```
sed -e 's|\x00ioctl\x00|\x00iqct1\x00|g;
        s|\x00dlsym\x00|\x00d15ym\x00|g;' mylib.so > libmylib.so
```

and we implement the two custom functions as something like

```
int iqct1(int fd, unsigned long request, void *data)
{
    /* For OP to implement! */
}
__asm__(".symver iqct1,iqct1@GLIBC_2.2.5");

void *d15ym(void *handle, const char *symbol)
{
    if (!strcmp(symbol, "ioctl"))
        return iqct1;
    else
    if (!strcmp(symbol, "dlsym"))
        return d15ym;
    else
        return dlsym(handle, symbol);
}
__asm__(".symver d15ym,d15ym@GLIBC_2.2.5");
```

Do check the versions correspond to the C library you use.  The corresponding .syms file for the above would contain just

{
    i1ct1;
    d15ym;
};

otherwise the implementation should be as in the practical example shown earlier in this answer.

Because the actual prototype for `ioctl()` is `int ioctl(int, unsigned long, ...);`, there are no quarantees that this will work for all general uses of `ioctl()`. In Linux, the second parameter is of type `unsigned long`, and the third parameter is either a pointer or a long or unsigned long -- in all Linux architectures pointers and longs/unsigned longs have the same size --, so it should work, unless the driver implementing the `ioctl()` is also closed, in which case you are simply hosed, and limited to either hoping this works, or switching to other hardware with proper Linux support and open-source drivers.

The above special-cases both original symbols, and hard-wires them to the replaced functions. (I call these *replaced* instead of *interposed* symbols, because we really do replace the symbols the `mylib.so` calls with these ones, rather than interpose calls to `ioctl()` and `dlsym()`.)

It is a rather brutish approach, but aside from using `sed` due to the lack of dynamic symbol redefinition support in `objcopy`, it is quite robust and clear as to what is done and what actually happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get it working.
mylib.so is a `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped`. I applied the `objcopy` as you proposed, but mylib.so still loads the ioctl from libc. Is there a way to check whether the redefinition of the symbol worked? I tried to check `objdump -T mylib.so | grep ioctl` and `readelf --syms mylib.so | grep ioctl` and all of them still refer to glibc. There is also no information regarding `my_ioctl` in both calls.

Comment: @bonanza: D'oh! binutils does not support redefining the symbols this way. I edited my answer to reflect the situation. A quick test shows that the nasty workaround -- renaming the dynamic library `ioctl()` to `iqct1()` (or similar) using a `sed` invocation -- seems to work for me here; could you test that approach?

Comment: Thanks again for your help and effort! I did what you suggested (the sed part). However, when I then want to `dlopen` the 'patched' mylib, `dlopen` drops an error: 'Function not implemented' (on the first try) and 'Invalid argument' on the second and all consecutive tries.

Comment: Is it possible that the first version (the code as written in my post) is not working because mylib does a `dlopen` and `dlsym` to get `ioctl` which circumvents my implementation of `ioctl`? If so, is there any way (and it is reasonable) to wrap `dlsym` also? In this case, how could a I load the real `dlsym` from libc if I have my own implementation of `dlsym` in my code?

Comment: @bonanza: You might need to add versioning information to the `iqct1` symbol (because your C library typically exports a specific version of it; `GLIBC_2.2.5` on mine -- remember that for `mylib.so`, your `iqct1()` should look exactly like the C library `ioctl()` does). Did you ensure that `iqct1()` has dynamic linkage (i.e., that your implementation is exported properly)? Does `mylib.so` refer to a dynamic symbol named `dlsym`?

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I tried adding the symbol versioning with the command you mentioned but compilation failed (please see my edit to the initial posting).  I also added there some `readelf` output from both libraries. I hope I understood you correctly: Regarding the exporting I added `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` for `iqct1`.

Comment: @bonanza: No, the visibility attribute is not enough; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36807145/1475978) for details on how you need to ensure `iqct1` is dynamically linkable. (TL;DR: when compiling, use `-rdynamic` or `-Wl,-dynamic-list,symbols.txt` with `iqct1` in `symbols.txt`.)

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate it! I finally exported the symbol and added the version (please see my edit) to the initial post. However, I still get the `dlopen` error saying that mylib couldn't find iqct1.

Comment: @bonanza: Darn; that sure indicates `mylib.so` uses `dlopen()`/`dlsym()` to obtain the function pointer to `ioctl()`. Augh; you'll need to interpose `dlsym()` also in the final binary. Could you post (or send me via e-mail; my address is shown on my home page, the link to which is in my profile) the full GLIBC symbol list from `mylib.so`, i.e. `objdump -T mylib.so | | awk '/GLIBC_/ { printf "%s@%s\n", $NF, $(NF-1) }' | sort`?

Comment: @bonanza: Scratch the previous request for symbols; I've added a practical example, and a supplementary description on how I would replace both `ioctl()` and `dlsym()` in `mylib.so` with `iqct1()` and `d15ym()`, respectively. It is quite important that `iqct1()` and `d15ym()` are linked in the final binary, as otherwise we'd need to ensure somehow that the dynamic libraries are loaded in order that quarantees `iqct1()` and `d15ym()` are provided early enough. That gets too messy, in my opinion.

Comment: Its working now, thanks so much! One last question: How safe is the 'patching' with `sed`? Meaning, how likely is it that really all calls to `ioctl` are 'redirected' to `iqct1`?

Comment: @bonanza: We *rename* the symbol, so it will affect all explicit references. Unless there is some other way (than normal dynamic linking) that the library can obtain a pointer to the function, it's pretty much foolproof. The risk is really that the `sed` command patches *too much*, like string `"ioctl"`. I recommend you verify that the `sed` command only modifies one instance of `ioctl` to `iqct1` and one `dlsym` to `d15ym` (using e.g. `cmp -b mylib.so libmylib.so`); if so, you should be completely covered.